# View size of file in human readable format with no rounding in macOS bash

Tags: bash, macos, shell

In bash I'm able to use `du -sh` to view file sizes in human readable formats, and `ls -lta` to view the full size in bytes. Is there a way to view the human readable amount without rounding? Examples below.

**du**

```
~ du -sh test.txt
 26G    test.txt
```

**ls**

```
 ~ ls -lta test.txt 
-rw-r--r--  1 username  staff  27992876444 Apr  2 10:53 test.txt
```

**desired**

```
 ~ some_command test.txt
26gb 72mb 89kb 412b
```

Comment: Neither `du` nor `ls` has the ability to output in that format. You'll have to write your own routine to do it.

Comment: Is there any other command or binary that does that? It wouldn't be difficult to write my own but I would've assumed that someone had already solved this problem before

Comment: Not that I know of.